# Setting client version for Java irc bot

Tags: java, bots, irc

I'm trying to build a irc bot with Java. Currently my problem is that I cannot get it to connect to Quakenet. I'm getting "Your client may not be compatible with this server." Which might be just because I haven't set any client version for this bot. How can I do that?

I'm aware that there are libraries for building irc bot with Java but I would like to create one from scratch to get more knowledge about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What that means is that the server is sending your client a message querying its version, and your client, if it's responding at all, isn't responding with a string that the server likes.  It has nothing to do with what software library (or version thereof) you're using.

I'd recommend reading RFC1459 (IRC protocol) and watching the raw traffic that is getting sent to your client to see what exactly is going on.  As Yogi Berra once said, "You observe a lot just by watching."

Comment: Thanks. However could you elaborate this little bit? I'm not sure how I could see more traffic as I think I'm currently trying to output everything to console.

Comment: Ultimately all you're doing is opening a socket.  Just print anything that comes from that socket to the console (in addition to whatever else you're doing with it.)  You'll see all kinds of fun stuff.  I wrote a bot from scratch many years ago but can't find the source.  My latest effort used the pIRC library.  It works nicely, but since you want to roll your own, that won't really help you.

Comment: That was the solution as well. It seems that to join IRC network I don't need to specify any version. Just Nick and username. In the end all I needed is:

    `Socket socket= new Socket(server, 6667);
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(soketti.getOutputStream()));
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soketti.getInputStream()));
  System.out.println("Starting login");
  // Login to server
  bw.write("NICK " + nickname + "\r\n");
  bw.write("USER " + login + " 8 * : robot\r\n");
  bw.flush();`